# How to change `user` name to other name like `client` in Codeigniter Rest_controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my current url using Codeigniter Rest_controller

```
http://localhost/api/user/id/1/format/xml
```

My expected output

```
http://localhost/api/client/id/1/format/xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got my answers after trying several times..

Here is my current code that cause `user` name

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Example
 *
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Rest Server
 * @category    Controller
 * @author      Phil Sturgeon
 * @link        http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/
*/

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Example extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Construct our parent class
        parent::__construct();

        // Configure limits on our controller methods. Ensure
        // you have created the 'limits' table and enabled 'limits'
        // within application/config/rest.php
        $this->methods['user_get']['limit'] = 500; //500 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['user_post']['limit'] = 100; //100 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['user_delete']['limit'] = 50; //50 requests per hour per user/key
    }

    function user_get()
    {
        if(!$this->get('id'))
        {
            $this->response(NULL, 400);
        }

        // $user = $this->some_model->getSomething( $this->get('id') );
        $users = array(
            1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com', 'fact' => 'Loves swimming'),
            2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com', 'fact' => 'Has a huge face'),
            3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => 'Is a Scott!', array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
        );

        $user = @$users[$this->get('id')];

        if($user)
        {
            $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        }

        else
        {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
        }
    }

    function user_post()
    {
        //$this->some_model->updateUser( $this->get('id') );
        $message = array('id' => $this->get('id'), 'name' => $this->post('name'), 'email' => $this->post('email'), 'message' => 'ADDED!');

        $this->response($message, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    function user_delete()
    {
        //$this->some_model->deletesomething( $this->get('id') );
        $message = array('id' => $this->get('id'), 'message' => 'DELETED!');

        $this->response($message, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    function users_get()
    {
        //$users = $this->some_model->getSomething( $this->get('limit') );
        $users = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com'),
            3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
        );

        if($users)
        {
            $this->response($users, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        }

        else
        {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any users!'), 404);
        }
    }


    public function send_post()
    {
        var_dump($this->request->body);
    }


    public function send_put()
    {
        var_dump($this->put('foo'));
    }
}
```

Just change to this code

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Example
 *
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Rest Server
 * @category    Controller
 * @author      Phil Sturgeon
 * @link        http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/
*/

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Example extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Construct our parent class
        parent::__construct();

        // Configure limits on our controller methods. Ensure
        // you have created the 'limits' table and enabled 'limits'
        // within application/config/rest.php
        $this->methods['client_get']['limit'] = 500; //500 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['client_post']['limit'] = 100; //100 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['client_delete']['limit'] = 50; //50 requests per hour per user/key
    }

    function client_get()
    {
        if(!$this->get('id'))
        {
            $this->response(NULL, 400);
        }

        // $user = $this->some_model->getSomething( $this->get('id') );
        $users = array(
            1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com', 'fact' => 'Loves swimming'),
            2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com', 'fact' => 'Has a huge face'),
            3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => 'Is a Scott!', array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
        );

        $user = @$users[$this->get('id')];

        if($user)
        {
            $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        }

        else
        {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
        }
    }

    function client_post()
    {
        //$this->some_model->updateUser( $this->get('id') );
        $message = array('id' => $this->get('id'), 'name' => $this->post('name'), 'email' => $this->post('email'), 'message' => 'ADDED!');

        $this->response($message, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    function client_delete()
    {
        //$this->some_model->deletesomething( $this->get('id') );
        $message = array('id' => $this->get('id'), 'message' => 'DELETED!');

        $this->response($message, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    function clients_get()
    {
        //$users = $this->some_model->getSomething( $this->get('limit') );
        $users = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com'),
            3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
        );

        if($users)
        {
            $this->response($users, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        }

        else
        {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any users!'), 404);
        }
    }


    public function send_post()
    {
        var_dump($this->request->body);
    }


    public function send_put()
    {
        var_dump($this->put('foo'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `application/config/routes.php`

`$route[’client/id/:num/format/xml’] = "user/id/$1/format/XML";`

For further information checkout [**this link**](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html).

Comment: How about both names `users` and `user` --> `clients` and `client` ?

Comment: I'm using webservices using REST in codeigniter...url can be change either to use `http://localhost/api/user/id/1/format/xml` or `http://localhost/api/users/id/1/format/xml`..

Comment: The most easier solution I could recommend is to set another route rule for plural. I.e just add the `s` to client and make another rule for users